# How much time will it take to develop MS Dynamics NAV integration using XML files

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I got new assignment in my workplace to integrate NAV 4.0 system with third party system using XML files. Integration will be based on XML file creation and storage of those files in predefined directories (i.e. it has to be a non-web-service approach, but a simple file-based approach).

Integration will cover only items, i.e. item and related data will be exported. System must have an ability to fully setup, what fields and tables (together with items) should be exported, i.e. item, item unit of measure, item sales prices etc. (later there might be more tables and more fields added to the system, so user should be able to setup things without help of developer). I mean that system should be somewhat fields and tables invariant, but all tables will be item related.

The process (export) should be executed with NAS and also there should be manual redo function (in case NAS fails).

Those other systems after handling exported data XML will produce error files in other predefined directories. System should accept those error XMLs (error XMLs will be imported back) from those systems and show that to user.

I am really struggling to give a reasonable estimate for this assignment. Could somebody give me a good wild guess, how much time this would take for a reasonable developer to do?

Comment: 1. What will cause item to be exported? Create/update/delete operations? 2. If certain `Item` card should be expected does it mean that bunch of related records from other tables should be exported as well? Or are they independent? 3. What should be done with imported error data? Only show it to user?

Comment: 1. On global modify trigger, all new Items will be marked as "to send". 2. Yes. But it should be defined in setup. Which fields and which related tables should be exported. 3. Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you need to implement something very similar to `Change Log` but with different setup. When global OnModify trigger is fired you put a record in `Integration log` table. In this table you will also have field like `Exported` which will be set to true when Nas exported the record. This will allow manual redo and check if everything is working. You will also be able to link error from response xml file with certain record in integration table if you export primary key in outgoing xml file.

It would take about 3 to 4 weeks in my opinion.

Comment: yes, if redo/logging is necessary you need more time, Mak Sim's estimation is probably right.

Answer (score 1):

it really depends of the xml files...for example if it's using namespaces then it's much harder. The scenario what you've mentioned in your post is suggests you'll need some additional setup tables as well. In version 4 there are no XMLport neither so you need to build them using Automation libraries.

I think we talking about 10-15 dev days + testing + documentation

Cheers!

Comment: And how will you know which data was already exported and wich is not for "manual redo"?

Comment: I think, there should be an integration log, which should show which items were exported. Also there could be a timestamp/mark on item table, that would also mark exported items.